# Update the properties of a sharepoint document via api rest

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Update the properties of a sharepoint document via api rest.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNTRA.png)
For example I want to edit in the document test.html the column test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update document name,try the following example.

```
function CreateListItemWithDetails(listName) {
    
    var item = {
        "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.Shared_x0020_DocumentsItem" },
        "FileLeafRef": "NBA2.PNG"           
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(9)",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "IF-MATCH": "*",
                   "X-HTTP-Method": "PATCH",
                   // Accept header: Specifies the format for response data from the server.
                   "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                   //Content-Type header: Specifies the format of the data that the client is sending to the server
                   "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                   // X-RequestDigest header: When you send a POST request, it must include the form digest value in X-RequestDigest header
                   "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**Updated:**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, could you tell me how to do this with Postman?

Comment: The value of Cookies and the value of X-RequestDigest where do I get them?.
It gives me this error:     error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "es-ES",
            "value": "El patrón no pudo resolver un tipo con el nombre 'SP.Data.Shared_x0020_DocumentsItem'. Cuando hay un patrón disponible, cada nombre de tipo se debe resolver en un tipo válido."
        }

Comment: You could get them in browser,or you could try to get by this way.https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/access-sharepoint-online-rest-api-via-postman-with-user-context/

Comment: If I have an access token with is it worth not?

Comment: If you have access token,you could call the rest api directly.http://pratapreddypilaka.blogspot.com/2018/05/sharepoint-online-authentication-for.html

Comment: Thanks it works, my error was in type I had to put SP.Data.Foldername. Although it gives me a status code 204 with no content. Would you know why?

Comment: Okay, thanks you!!, what I wanted to know was because 200 did not come out, but I knew that status 2x was correct

Comment: If the column were metadata how can I update that value?

Comment: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4758

Comment: I have read the article but it has not helped me. I have a column with metadata and can only have the values ​​to sleep and wake up. How could I change if a column has the sleep value change it to the wake up value